# Excel - Finding all values in one column for unique values in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, transpose

I have an Excel table that looks like this:

```
Code | Description
-------------------------
A    | Desc1
A    | Desc2
B    | Desc3
C    | Desc4
C    | Desc5
C    | Desc6
...
```

I need to find all the `Descriptions` for each unique `Code`.  For example I want a table that looks like this:

```
Code | Description1 | Description2 | Description3
-----------------------------------------------------
A    | Desc1        | Desc2        |
B    | Desc3        |              |
C    | Desc4        | Desc5        | Desc6
```

Is there a way to do this in Excel?  I tried Pivot Tables, but had no luck.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is in `A1:B7` including headers as you show, enter whatever headers you want in `C1:F1`, but make sure the `Code` column values you are looking for is in `C2` and going down. Like `C3 = B` and `C4 = D`. If you don't know all the `Code` column values there is a simple unique extract formula that can get them from the `Code` column for you.

In `C2` enter this formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> keys

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$7, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$1:$C1, $A$2:$A$7), 0))
```

In `D2` enter this formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> keys and then you can drag it to the right and down to populate your new table.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$7, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C2:C2,$B$2:$B$7)+IF($A$2:$A$7<>$C2, 1, 0), 0)), 0)
```

Currently this will display a `0` in cells that do not have any new description to display.
This also will only work if your original data is sorted by the `Code` column.*Edit- Nevermind, it does work with unsorted values.*

I hope this helps.

#### EDIT* Added a Photo

### Read more about this formula combo here ► [How to extract a unique distinct list from a column in excel](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/)

[image: EDIT* Added a Photo]

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I'm trying it and getting all 0's.

Comment: Did you enter it as an array with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER? I tried it again and it works for me.

Comment: Several comments: (1) Good job!  (2) I don’t understand what you’re saying in the first paragraph.  (3) It would be nice if you would explain the formulas.  (4) What do you mean, “This will work only if your original data is sorted by the `Code` column.”?  I tried your formulas with unsorted codes and [it worked just fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3Yny5.png).  (Note that I changed your formula to `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$7, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C2:C2,$B$2:$B$7)+IF($A$2:$A$7<>$C2, 1, 0), 0)), "-")` to display dashes instead of zeroes; you could just as well say `""` and display blanks.)

Comment: @Scott (1) Thanks, (2) I was defining where the data is and where I created the new table since the formula uses cell references that can be different. (3) Read more here [How to extract a unique distinct list from a column in excel](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/). (4) Wow, nevermind, you're right it does work. I may have been thinking of a different formula combo. - Thanks,