# Combining multiple rows into one

Tags: microsoft-excel

From input as below:

```
Last Name  First Name  Job Title   Date Hired  Description Field Name  Value   SSN/Fed ID
AL  V   Assistant   12/08/2008      Driver License Expiration Date  2/23/16 364
AL  V   Assistant   12/08/2008  expiration date Physical DOT Exp.   09/17/2014  364
AL  V   Assistant   12/08/2008      Fingerprinting Registered   3/14/13 364
AL  V   Assistant   12/08/2008      Fingerprinting Received 3/28/13 364
AL  V   Assistant   12/08/2008      Child Abuse Mailed  3/21/13 364
AL  V   Assistant   12/08/2008      Child Abuse Received    04/04/2013  364
AL  V   Assistant   12/08/2008      Annual Cert-Violations  3/9/12  364
AL  V   Assistant   12/08/2008      MVR Last Ran    3/20/12 364
AL  V   Assistant   12/08/2008      Driver S Card Exp       364
AL  V   Assistant   12/08/2008      Driver Recert Due       364
AL  V   Assistant   12/08/2008      Physical SB Exp.        364
AL  V   Assistant   12/08/2008      Criminal Received   3/18/13 364
AL  V   Assistant   12/08/2008      Act 24  12/23/2011  364
AL  V   Assistant   12/08/2008      Fingerprinting ID # PAE 364
AL  V   Assistant   12/08/2008      Physical NON-DOT Exp.       364
AL  V   Assistant   12/08/2008      Fingerprinting Went 3/21/13 364
AL  V   Assistant   12/08/2008      Fingerprinting Resubmittal      364
BA  S   Assistant   07/14/2009      Driver License Expiration Date  2/22/2014   190
BA  S   Assistant   07/14/2009  expiration date Physical DOT Exp.   2/1/14  190
BA  S   Assistant   07/14/2009      Fingerprinting Registered   6/17/2009   190
BA  S   Assistant   07/14/2009      Fingerprinting Received 6/25/2009   190
BA  S   Assistant   07/14/2009      Child Abuse Mailed  2/17/2009   190
BA  S   Assistant   07/14/2009      Child Abuse Received    2/26/2009   190
BA  S   Assistant   07/14/2009      Annual Cert-Violations  03/14/2012  190
BA  S   Assistant   07/14/2009      MVR Last Ran    03/20/2012  190
BA  S   Assistant   07/14/2009      Driver S Card Exp       190
BA  S   Assistant   07/14/2009      Driver Recert Due       190
BA  S   Assistant   07/14/2009      Physical SB Exp.        190
BA  S   Assistant   07/14/2009      Criminal Received   2/22/13 190
BA  S   Assistant   07/14/2009      Act 24  12/22/2011  190
BA  S   Assistant   07/14/2009      Fingerprinting ID # PAE 190
BA  S   Assistant   07/14/2009      Physical NON-DOT Exp.       190
BA  S   Assistant   07/14/2009      Fingerprinting Went 6/17/2009   190
BA  S   Assistant   07/14/2009      Fingerprinting Resubmittal      190
```

How can I combine rows for a result as follows?

```
Last Name  First Name  Title   DOHire  DL Exp Date SS  Physical DOT    Fingerprint Registered  Fingerprint Received    Child Abuse Mailed  Child Abuse Received    Annual Cert MVR last run    Driver S    Driver Recert   Physical SB Criminal Received   Act 24  Fingerprinting ID#  Physical Non DOT    Fingerprinting Went Fingerprint Resubmittal
Al  V   Assistant   12/8/2008   2/23/2016   364 9/17/2012   3/14/2013   3/28/2013   3/21/2013   4/4/2013    3/9/2012    3/20/2013               3/18/2013   12/23/2013  PAE     3/21/2013   
Ba  S   Assistant   7/14/2008   2/22/2014   190 2/1/2014    6/17/2009   6/25/2009   2/17/2009   2/26/2009   3/14/2012   3/20/2012               2/22/2013   12/22/2011  PAE     6/17/2009
```

Comment: What is your question and what have you tried?

Comment: I think this can be done with Excel Formulas as I did here, [Excel - Finding all values in one column for unique values in another column](http://superuser.com/questions/604152/excel-finding-all-values-in-one-column-for-unique-values-in-another-column/604166#604166) It is not an exact answer but It could help you start to parse the data the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an Excel pivot table. Pivot tables take data rows that share several key columns and one or a few data elements and convert them into a single row per key, with multiple aggregated columns.

You are not doing a traditional pivot function, because you are not summing values, but it should work for you.

Pivot tables can be confusing at first, so I recommend you start with just 3 or so test rows, get them to show up as your 3 columns, then add a second user with 3 test rows and make sure it still works correctly, then add all of your dozen or so pivots.

Google excel pivot tutorial or check out this:
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-Pivot-Tables-in-Excel

Answer (score 0):

If your data originally is in `A1:H35` with headers as you show we can build your new table in `I1:AE3`

[image]

### (1st Formula)

The key value in each row to identify a unique is the SSN/FedID so in order to get a list of the unique values of SSN, in cell `M2` ( Our new SSN/FedID column) type in this array formula. Be sure to enter with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to make it an array.

> `=INDEX(H$2:H$35, MATCH(0, COUNTIF(M$1:M1, H$2:H$35), 0))`

This will populate column `M:M` with the unique SSN numbers so we can use those to fill the rest of the new table.
[image]

### (2nd Formula)

Cell `I2` can be filled down and to the right to populate all the `I2:L3` cells with the formula...

> `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH($M2,$H:$H,0))`

The new headings here are corresponding to our original data headers.

> `I1` = `"LastName"`|
> `J1` = `"FirstName"`|
> `K1` = `"JobTitle"`|
> `L1` = `"DateHired"`

[image]

### (3rd Formula)

Now we have to fill in the unique `"FieldName"` values as our new headers starting in cell `N1` type in this array formula and be sure to enter with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to make it an array.

> `=INDEX($F$2:$F$35, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($L$1:L1, $F$2:$F$35), 0))`

Once entered you can drag and copy this formula to the right, to fill cells `N1:AE1`.

[image]

### (4th Formula)

Now in cell `N2` you can enter this formula.

> `=SUMIFS($G:$G,$F:$F,N$1,$H:$H,$M2)`

You can now drag that formula down and to the right. It will return a `"0"` if the cell was blank in the original table. If these cells are fomatted as a Date and it will show `1/0/1900`.
You can avoid this by changing the formula with an `IF()` statement to say if 0 then return `"-"` or whatever you like such as this...

> `=IF(SUMIFS($G:$G,$F:$F,N$1,$H:$H,$M2)=0,"-",SUMIFS($G:$G,$F:$F,N$1,$H:$H,$M2))`

[image]

-I hope this helps,

More Info on the array formulas I used can be found here...
[How to extract a unique distinct list from a column in excel](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/)